# Fix the [transporter] malfunction

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

I've recently stumbled across [transporter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transporter), with currently 1 watcher and 36 questions. There's no tag wiki at all either.

Addressing [the points Shog9 makes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191):

- > Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

  It doesn't add much and it's certainly not unambiguous. There's [AnyLogic's transporter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71462825/5211833) which seems to be a module covering physical transport, [node.js transporter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71332813/5211833) which communicates between elements, [ios transporter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70908054/5211833), [magento transporter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68939227/5211833), and [mongoDB transporter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70036113/5211833) for starters.
  So whilst all different uses *transport* something, what and how they're transporting is rather different.
- > Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

  Transporting what? It's meta information at best.
- > Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?

  It might in some cases, but most questions could easily do without it.
- > Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

  No, see the first bullet point.

Comment: looks active and alive, with few posts with negative score, ikr snx other tag with low frequent visits

Comment: Seems like this needs to be disambiguated into three different tags.  I took the liberty of adding the [tag:tag-disambiguation] tag to the request, though please feel free to remove it if it's not in the spirit of your request.

Comment: @RyanM make that at least five, just from the 10 newest questions, see my edit.

Comment: @nbk considering that only gets a question month, and downvoted questions are deleted every 30 days, I would say that your view is very likely biased.

Comment: @Braiam i support that people add tags ike crazy, so that interesting combinations can be posted and lead to new and interesting constellations, which makes the site interesting for professionals. synomize ok that is fine by me

Comment: @nbk nah, I prefer my constellations fixed thankyouverymuch. There's no point in having tag for every keyword.

Comment: @Braiam i don't search for new tags for "my" collection, but read many questions associated with topic i care about and i comment on them or answer, that akes life interesting, at least the short time in am here